# Cloud storage services and session-based file-URLs

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, google-cloud-storage, access-control

I have the following use-case that I am seeking a solution for:

*Our website shares files to our clients. The files are stored on a 3rd party cloud service, the file access permissions on our website. When a client on our site requests a file that he has permission to see, it will be served directly from the cloud service (instead of through our own webserver, using our CPU, RAM and bandwidth).*

I see services like Amazon S3 and Google Cloud Storage use an approach with a signed URL with a timeout for this purpose, but I would prefer a solution where that URL is only available to the client who requested the resource (and not everyone who has the link during the lifecycle of the URL). The reason for this is that it feels wrong to rely on a duration based un an arbitrary length instead of utilizing a one-time token or in any other way validate the access to the resource before the request is completed.

Does any of the major services provide a feature that would allow for this? Or is it considered "safe enough" to protect sensitive data behind a random URL + timeout period (to me it feels like the answer to the latter is "no")?

Comment: Given that HTTP is stateless, the notion of being "the client" who requested the resource is fuzzy.  How is "the client" identified? Cookies? Spoofable.  You sign the link on demand with a very short expiration time, and redirect the downloader to it -- download time doesn't need to be factored into expiration, because the *start* time of the download is what counts... and if the exchange is over https, then how will other people come to possess the link?  One option with CloudFront in front of S3, is that signed CloudFront URLs can include a restriction on the client's IP address.

Comment: Are cookies more spoofable than URL parameters when restricting to https? I can think of a protocol that would let the web-server and the cloud-server to establish the validity of a request using a session identifier, however this would require additional requests from the client in addition to some server-to-server communication. The overhead would maybe not make it worthwhile. However, it still does not feel "safe enough" to protect files behind a random string. The client could still share it to others within the timeframe, and the full URL could also be recorded in various logs etc.

Comment: Requests sent over https are *not* captured in access logs unless the https connections are being hijacked, and if that is true, the content is already accessible via the same mechanism. No, cookies are not more spoofable than query strings, but the point was that they are not *less* spoofable even though they're less visible to the user... yet they are often precisely a "random string" that would allow access to the user's entire account, not just one file.

Comment: @kvitso - The client could also just download the http resource and then share the contents. Signed URLs are effectively short-lived bearer tokens. The algorithms used to produce them make them intractable to guess, and using them is considered best practice. Your proposed scheme doesn't sound any more secure.